# How to handle inventory details, getting an error?

Tags: netsuite

This is my code:

```
var invAdjRec = nlapiCreateRecord('inventoryadjustment');
var lotNumber = "lot123456";
invAdjRec.setFieldValue('account', '850');
invAdjRec.selectNewLineItem('inventory');
invAdjRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'item', '2904');
invAdjRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'location', '3');
invAdjRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'adjustqtyby', '10');
var inventoryDetail =   invAdjRec.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('inventory','inventorydetail');         

inventoryDetail.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');      inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'issueinventorynumber', lotNumber);
inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', 10);
inventoryDetail.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');      inventoryDetail.commit();
invAdjRec.commitLineItem('inventory');
nlapiSubmitRecord(invAdjRec);
```

This is my error:

> Please enter value(s) for: Serial/Lot Number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like, according to that error message, you are just missing: serialnumber.

```
invAdjRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory','serialnumber',lotNumber);
```

Comment: Where to i get serialnumber@W3BGUY

Comment: Serialnumber is the field id for the Serial/Lot Number:  Look here: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/item.html

Comment: I used this code but it's not working. the same error showing@W3BGUY

Comment: Did you verify the data that is in your lotNumber field?  And verify that you have access to that field with the login that you are using?

Comment: @W3BGUY It looks like he's using Advanced Inventory Management. There should be no serialnumber field in the inventory sublist then.

Answer (score 1):

The `issueinventorynumber` field is a select field of a [inventorynumber](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/inventorynumber.html) record and expects an internal id passed in. If the `lot` you wish to set exists, you can examine an existing record that uses it to obtain the id. If the Lot Number does not yet exist, you may not be able to create it.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you use **issueinventorynumber** field id as the quantity to be adjusted, but this can only be used for negative inventory adjustments. For positive inventory adjustments, you need to use **receiptinventorynumber** instead

Answer (score -2):

There's another field not listed in the record browser that must be set:

```
subrecordInvDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                fieldId: 'receiptinventorynumber',
                value: serialNumber
            });
```